# Java Learning Tasks + Solution (mini project)

Tags: java, resources, project

I'm currently reading Head First Java, and I am wondering if there any websites or books? that I could go to that would set out some sort of task or assignment for me to practice on. In order to gain a better practical understanding of java. Even something like a mini project and then at the end I could see a completed solution that would show me areas I could of improved my code.

Even a Step by Step project tutorial for creating a game perhaps?

Has anyone got any resources like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

[Code Kata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/2007/01/code_kata_backg.html) is a good place to find various programming assignments, and those are not language-specific. So, there's no real "one solution" to them, but they are a good way to get you thinking about different classes of problems.

I'm pretty sure I've seen another site much like that, but can't seem to think of which one it might have been right now.

Answer (score 5):

Or, if you are mthematical inclined, try [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

Comment: Ah, that was the other one I was thinking of. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at this site it has lots of mini project related to java

http://www.1000projects.com/new/java/mini/main.html

Java Student Projects

http://mindprod.com/project/projects.html

Answer (score 2):

[Example Depot](http://www.exampledepot.com/) is a great place for real-life java examples. Try looking at examples and combining them to create a real application.

If you want more theoretical assignments: http://www.psc-consulting.ca/fenske/cpjava.htm